# PHP - Show the price of the selected product

Tags: php, jquery

I want selectbox value Price show a Input.

[image]

This is Combobox Code (TEKLİF VERİLECEK ÜRÜN #1)

```
<div class="col-md-3">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label style="color:black;">TEKLİF VERİLECEK ÜRÜN #1    </label>
   <select name="CompanyData" style="color:#8940D3; border: solid 1px #8940D3;" class="form-control">
    <?php
     $ProductData = mysqli_query($dbconnect, "SELECT * FROM product");
      while($DBProduct = mysqli_fetch_array($ProductData)) {
     ?>
      <option name="ProductDataID" value="<?php echo $DBProduct['product_id'] ?>"><?php echo $DBProduct['product_name'] ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
   </select>
 </div>
```

And, I want "product_price" column show this input.

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label style="color:black;">ÜRÜN FİYATI #1</label>
 <input style="color:#8940D3; border: solid 1px black; background-color:silver" name="tekliftarihi" required="" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="" value="">
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question or state what the problem is.

Comment: How do I call the price I want listed?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the change in the value of the selectbox and put it on input.

You should do something like this with jQuery:

```
$("select[name=CompanyData]").change(function(){
  $("input[name=tekliftarihi]").val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Okey, where do i write my column?

Comment: If you have the price paired with the id, you can just add something like this

`<option price="<?=$DBProduct['price']?>" name="ProductDataID" value="<?=$DBProduct['product_id']?>"><?=$DBProduct['product_name']?></option>`

And then with javascript:

`$("select[name=CompanyData]").change(function(){
  $("input[name=tekliftarihi]").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("price"));
});`